# What is MANN and whom we say I (main).

Tags: karma, atma

i want to know what is mann. often we say mann nahi kar raha. either we say i don't want to do this. is I(main) and Mann are same.

Comment: Mann (mind) is different from the I (ahankara). Because we say "My mind is feeling bad today" So, who/what is saying that is the "I" and it's different from the mind.